# How can I debug my failed deployment on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

Trying to deploy a Node app and usually have no issues at all. Now I'm having TypeScript resolution errors that only fail on Heroku but work locally and I have no idea how to test it ON Heroku.

I know I can do `heroku run bash` but then I'm just in an empty directory without my code.

I'd like to `heroku run bash` after the failed build and look around and run my commands as Heroku would so I can see why I'm having module resolution errors.

Can't find anything about it on Google whatsoever

Comment: are you tailing heroku? and what is the exact error?

Comment: looking at the heroku logs and the issue is finding modules. The only way I can debug is to add a script like: `"heroku-postbuild": "ls -la src/somewhere"` and keep running it. It'd be nice to just heroku run bash and start playing around with my code there too